# Why can't vim process .vimrc when winheight option isn't set twice?

Tags: vim

I'm using the following options to make the split I'm focussing on the biggest on the screen. When bouncing between splits, window sizes get updated accordingly:

```
set winwidth=84
set winheight=5
set winminheight=5
set winheight=999
```

That works fine, however, you see that there are two definitions of `winheight`, which is kind of odd. I removed the first `winheight` declaration to see if things would work the same. Unfortunately, vim throws the error that it can't process my .vimrc file.

So, to clarify things, I stole this configuration from somebody's .vimrc. There must be a reason, why this options has to be set twice but I couldn't find something useful in the help.

Do you know, why vim throws the error in that case?

Comment: @FDinoff I don't thing that the rest of my .vimrc is important, since these are the only win settings I have and the problem is also with just these options reproducable.

Comment: I feel like this is supposed maximizes a split's height and give a sizable width. I would have you look at `:h CTRL-W__`. I would also imagine that if you always maximizing splits then why use splits at all? Just use 1 window and switch buffers via `:b` or whatever your favorite buffer switching method is.

Comment: @PeterRincker well the splits are not entirely maximized, you can always the at list 5 rows from another split. So it's just about bringing focus to the split i'm currently in.

Answer (score 3):

If the error you’re getting is `E591`:

```
E591: 'winheight' cannot be smaller than 'winminheight': winminheight=5
```

the problem may be simply one of ordering. By default, `winheight` is `1`. Without the first `winheight` setting, you’re attempting to set a `winminheight` larger than the current `winheight`, which obviously causes problems (and results in the error).

I think that the duplicate declaration is also simply a matter of ordering. Attempting to start Vim up with the `winheight=999` moved up before the `winminheight` setting gives me the alternate error

```
E36: Not enough room
```

Thus, if you want both to set the `winheight` to its maximum (`999`) and to set the `winminheight` to something more reasonable than its default (`1`), this may be the only workable approach.

Comment: Totally makes sense thank you! However, I don't get the 591 error, I just get `Error detected while processing .vimrc`.

Comment: Indeed! Hmm — I get both (and a line number, even). I’m using terminal MacVim and have the four lines at the end of my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Terminal MacVim or Terminal Vim? I have a plain Terminal Vim installation (installed through home brew).

Comment: Huh — no, I have terminal Vim through Homebrew too. As long as it’s terminal Vim, though, I’m not sure of why it wouldn’t be giving you the error code (that’s just my wild guess, that it might be different in a GUI Vim version).