# How to make Vim open a new window even if there is not enough room

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim in Rolodex mode so that the active window is always expanded to occupy as much space as there is, but so that the inactive windows have at least 7 lines of space each (as in [Why can't vim process .vimrc when winheight option isn't set twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336553/why-cant-vim-process-vimrc-when-winheight-option-isnt-set-twice)).

The relevant lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
set winheight=7
set winminheight=7
set winheight=999
```

This works nice, but there is one problem. If I try to open more windows with `:sp` so that there isn't sufficient room to give 7 lines for each window, Vim prints the following error: `E36: Not enough room`. What I want is that if there is not enough room, Vim should anyway open a new window and just reduce the minimum window height of all windows as much as needed, and later if any window would be closed, the minimum window height should go up again (so that the window minimum size would again increase up to 7). In other words: **How can I make Vim consider window minimum height as an ideal, not a strict requirement?**

I have also tried [Golden Ratio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3690), but in Golden Ratio there are 2 problems: the inactive windows become very small, and the inactive windows also have unequal sizes, some inactive windows may have 3 lines and some only 1 line.

Comment: Would you be willing to change your workflow by changing from "Rolodex mode" to using a buffer approach? You could `set hidden` and create some mappings for `:bn` and `:bp` and have a very similar setup. Additionally you can use `:b` to go directly to the buffer which I believe would be an improvement.

Comment: @PeterRincker I could try the buffer approach too, but I like to be able to see several files on screen at once. Anyway, by expanding Ben's answer I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the initial split, I would use a try...catch...endtry block to split if possible, and adjust the window heights if not possible. For example, this shows the method (but is not smart enough to figure out how small to make the windows):

```vim
command! Split call MakeRoomAndSplit()

function! MakeRoomAndSplit()
  try
    split
  catch /E36:/
    let &winheight=&winminheight
    set winminheight=2
    set winheight=999
    split
  endtry
endfun
```

To get your window height back, I think you can do something similar in autocmds to detect a closed window and adjust the height accordingly. Example:

```vim
augroup WINHEIGHT
  au!
  autocmd WinEnter * if exists('t:numwindows') && t:numwindows > winnr('$') | call IncreaseWinSize() | endif
  autocmd WinEnter * let t:numwindows = winnr('$')
augroup END

function! IncreaseWinSize()
  let oldheight = &winminheight
  try
    set winheight=7
    set winminheight=7
    set winheight=999
  catch /E36:/
    let &winheight=oldheight
    let &winminheight=&winheight
    set winheight=999
  endtry
endfun
```

Answer (score 1):

By expanding Ben's answer, I got what I wanted. Here's my solution:

**Edit:** Fixed a bug in opening file `foo` with `:Split foo`.

```vim
set winheight=7
set winminheight=7
set winheight=999

" adjust minimum window size down from 7 to 1 and up from 1 to 7 as needed.
" this is a hack, but it works.

" code to adjust minimum window size down from 7 to 1 begins here.

command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit7(<q-args>)

function! OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow(...)
    :let combinedinput = join(a:000)
    :let inputlength = (strlen(combinedinput))
    :let lastchar = strpart(combinedinput, inputlength-1)
    if (inputlength == 0)
        " opens a new window with the current file.
        " if current buffer has no name, opens file viewer in a new window.
        :execute "Hexplore" bufname("%")
    else
        if (lastchar == '/')
            " opens file viewer in a new window.
            " directory names must end with '/',
            " luckily autocompletion does that.
            :execute "Hexplore" fnameescape(resolve(join(a:000)))
        elseif (lastchar == '~')
            " opens file viewer in a new window.
            :execute "Hexplore" fnameescape(resolve(join(a:000)))
        elseif (lastchar == '.')
            " opens file viewer in a new window.
            :execute "Hexplore" fnameescape(resolve(join(a:000)))
        else
            " opens the file in a new window.
            :execute ":split" fnameescape(resolve(join(a:000)))
        endif
    endif
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit7(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=6
        set winheight=999
        command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit6(<q-args>)
        call call('MakeRoomAndSplit6', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit6(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=5
        set winheight=999
        command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit5(<q-args>)
        call call('MakeRoomAndSplit5', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit5(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=4
        set winheight=999
        command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit4(<q-args>)
        call call('MakeRoomAndSplit4', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit4(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=3
        set winheight=999
        command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit3(<q-args>)
        call call('MakeRoomAndSplit3', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit3(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=2
        set winheight=999
        command! -nargs=* -complete=file Split call MakeRoomAndSplit2(<q-args>)
        call call('MakeRoomAndSplit2', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

function! MakeRoomAndSplit2(...)
    try
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    catch /E36:/
        let &winheight=&winminheight
        set winminheight=1
        set winheight=999
        call call('OpenFileOrDirectoryInNewWindow', a:000)
    endtry
endfun

" code to adjust minimum window size down from 7 to 1 ends here.

" code to adjust minimum window size up from 1 to 7 begins here.

augroup WINHEIGHT
    au!
    autocmd WinEnter * if exists('t:numwindows') && t:numwindows > winnr('$') | call IncreaseWinSize7() | endif
    autocmd WinEnter * let t:numwindows = winnr('$')
augroup END

function! IncreaseWinSize7()
    try
        set winheight=7
        set winminheight=7
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize6()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize6()
    try
        set winheight=6
        set winminheight=6
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize5()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize5()
    try
        set winheight=5
        set winminheight=5
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize4()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize4()
    try
        set winheight=4
        set winminheight=4
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize3()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize3()
    try
        set winheight=3
        set winminheight=3
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize2()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize2()
    try
        set winheight=2
        set winminheight=2
        set winheight=999
    catch /E36:/
        :call IncreaseWinSize1()
    endtry
endfun

function! IncreaseWinSize1()
    set winheight=1
    set winminheight=1
    set winheight=999
endfun

" code to adjust minimum window size up from 1 to 7 ends here.
```

Comment: Nice! That's cleaner than the recursive method I was toying with before I decided what I had was close enough for example's sake. :-)